# Spring-Boot mysql output without \r\n signs

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

I have this output from  a mysql DB with a JSON field:

[image]

I know I could use replace to eliminate the \r \n and \ , but especially the last one is a problem and could occur also in the normal text.

Is there a way to get the output without these signs?
I remember there was a way but I dont know anymore what it was... maybe also changing the collation in the DB from utf8mb4_general_ci to something other? Dont really know how this is called to google it...

Comment: In that way it is not possible, you want to preserve new lines and whitespaces for your strings but want to remove whitespaces in all other cases. correct? well, trim removes all whitespace, left-right removes whitespaces at the start or end, but not in-between. sanitize your string before adding it to the database.

Comment: Hm ok, I just need a readable JSON without \r\n also the \ in for example \"data\" seem to disturb, when I use: f.setFormJSON(f.getFormJSON().trim()); I still have the \r\n ... which is strange